# Java renameTo() leaving cifs* files on samba mount

Tags: java, samba, cifs

I have a linux java program that is reading and writing to a CIFS mounted Windows file share. See code snippet at bottom.

After execution, there are files named "cifs*" left in the directory. If the target directory is on the local file system, the code works like a champ. However, if the target directory is a CIFS mounted Windows file share, I get the left-over files. I'm not sure what configuration changes I need to make to fix. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
FileRenameMutex myFileRenameMutex = new FileRenameMutex("/WindowsMount/MoveLock");

class FileRenameMutex
{
    // global variables
    String lockFileBasename;
    String unusedExtension = "_Unused";
    String unusedFilename;
    String inUseFilename;
    String localMachineAddress;
    String formattedTime;

    // log4j logger for this class
    public static Logger logMutex = Logger.getLogger(FileRenameMutex.class.getName());

    public FileRenameMutex(String _lockFileBase) {
        this.lockFileBasename = _lockFileBase;
        logMutex.debug("FileRenameMutex: Constructor, with file " + lockFileBasename + "   user = " + System.getProperty("user.name"));
        try {
            localMachineAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
            //localMachineAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            localMachineAddress = "UNKNOWN_HOST";
            logMutex.error("   Could not determine host address. " + e.getMessage());
        }

        // set the file names
        unusedFilename = lockFileBasename + unusedExtension;
        inUseFilename = lockFileBasename + "_" + localMachineAddress;

        logMutex.debug("   Local machine = " + localMachineAddress);
        logMutex.debug("   Unused file name = " + this.unusedFilename);
        logMutex.debug("   In Use file name = " + this.inUseFilename);

    }
    public boolean tryAcquire() throws InterruptedException {
        boolean returnVal = false;
        File unusedFile = new File(unusedFilename);
        File inUseFile  = new File(inUseFilename);
        formattedTime = new Date().toString();
        String inUseText = "This file created by the Alfresco cron job to MoveFileAndCreateDir "
                           + "(move files from Unfiled to Filed folders).\n"
                           + "Running on " + localMachineAddress + "\n Started at " + formattedTime + "\n";
        try {
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(inUseFile);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            // attempt to rename file
            logMutex.debug("   Attempting to rename mutex file " + unusedFilename + " to " + inUseFilename);
            if ( unusedFile.renameTo(inUseFile) ) {
                logMutex.debug("      Rename to inUse successful");
                out.write(inUseText);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                returnVal = true;  // lock was acquired
            } else {
                // System.out.println("Rename to inUse failed");
                logMutex.error("      Rename of " + unusedFilename + " to " + inUseFilename + " failed in tryAcquire().");
            }
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            throw new InterruptedException("Error acquiring lock in tryAcquire(): " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return returnVal;
    }

    public void release() {
        File unusedFile = new File(unusedFilename);
        File inUseFile  = new File(inUseFilename);
        String unusedText = "This file was last by the Alfresco cron job to MoveFileAndCreateDir "
                           + "Ran on " + localMachineAddress + "\n Started at " + formattedTime + "\n";
        try {
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(inUseFile);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            out.write(unusedText);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            // attempt to rename file
            logMutex.debug("   Attempting to rename active mutex file " + inUseFilename + " back to " + unusedFilename);
            if ( inUseFile.renameTo(unusedFile) ) {
                logMutex.debug("      Rename back to unused successful");
            } else {
                logMutex.error("      Rename of " + inUseFilename + " to " + unusedFilename + " failed in release().");
            }
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            logMutex.error("Error resetting lock file in release(): " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }  // release()

}  // end of class FileRenameMutex
```

Comment: Note that it appears the renameTo(inUseFile) code creates a file "inUseFile" even if the "unusedFile" doesn't exist when running on a samba mounted file share. This sure seems wrong to me.

Comment: What's your Java version? Also, try to delete a file on your CIFS mount using Java code, maybe it's a simple permission problem where temp files can be created but not deleted.